# Non-linear editor for design spec documents

Tags: software-development, gui, user-interface, documentation-viewer, visual-design

My design team has been using Microsoft Word via Sharepoint to deliver UX specs to our developers. Our documents include a section for: final visuals, content, wireframes, interaction notes, and business analysis flows. In short, these MS Word documents are NOT short and are impossible to navigate as they are static linear documents. I would not wish these documents on anyone.

What my team needs (no compromises):

- A design spec that contains IX, BA, Visuals, Content, & attached files
- Simultaneous editing
- Version control
- A non-linear format with navigation
- PC & Mac support

What won't work: Axure, RTF docs & PDFs

What I heard others use: Zurb tools, Jira, a Wiki

**What solution would you strongly recommend?** Thanks in advance for the help.